# set all fields in subdocument to false, then set the second one to true in a single query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose I have the following the document structure.

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "depots": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "isFavourite": true
      },
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "isFavourite": false
      },
      {
        "_id": 3,
        "isFavourite": true
      },
      {
        "_id": 4,
        "isFavourite": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to write a **single update query** which filters for the document with `_id: 1` and first sets every `isFavourite` value to `false` and then sets the second `isFavourite` value (or any specified index) to `true`.

The resulting document should look like this.

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "depots": [
      {
        "_id": 1,
        "isFavourite": false
      },
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "isFavourite": true
      },
      {
        "_id": 3,
        "isFavourite": false
      },
      {
        "_id": 4,
        "isFavourite": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I tried:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "depots.isFavourite": false
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "depots.2.isFavourite": true
    }
  }
])
```

Yet strangely this does not work. See the linked playground for the result of this query.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ffp8B8BVuXA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the index as a dot notation only works when the update is not a pipeline.

One option is to "rebuild" the array using `$reduce`, which allow us to use the size of the currently built array to find the item with the requested index, and then `$mergeObjects` it with the updated field and value:

```
db.collection.update(
{_id: 1},
[
  {$set: {"depots.isFavourite": false}},
  {$set: {
      depots: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$depots",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              [
                {$cond: [
                    {$eq: [{$size: "$$value"}, requestedIndex]},
                    {$mergeObjects: ["$$this", {isFavourite: true}]},
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QtJCeV3YrFr)

Comment: Really good! This certainly works for me.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
{
  "$set": {
    "depots.$[y].isFavourite": false,
    "depots.$[x].isFavourite": true
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "x._id": 2
    },
    {
      "y._id": {
        $ne: 2
      }
    }
  ],
  "multi": true
})
```

Explained:

Set two arrayFilters x & y that match the two conditions ...

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GG_8dfef-o0)

Comment: The OP requests  to use the index of the array item, not the `_id` of it. But I always love to see your solutions @R2D2

Comment: Nice! This actually works too for me since I can also use the `_id`. Should have clarified this in the question. Sadly I can only accept one answer :(

Comment: Ah indeed @nimrod serok reply seems to answer to the exact request if based on index so he diserved the acceptance ;)